# Is it true that for a matrix A, $A^TAx=\sigma^2 x$ where $\sigma$ is a singular value for skew symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does $A^TAx=\sigma^2 x$ where $\sigma$ is a singular value for skew symmetric matrices?

Comment: If $x$ is a right singular value of $A$ corresponding to $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

That's true for any $A$. The singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. In other words, $\sigma$ is a singular value for $A$ if and only if there exists nonzero $x$ with $$A^TAx=\sigma^2x.$$